# Calling a Function in Matlab with Symbolic Functions as Arguments

Tags: matlab, function

I have written the following `Matlab` function:

```
function EulerMethod(t_min,t_max,h,f,Y,yzero)

tlist = t_min:h:t_max;

N = (t_max - t_min)/h;

ylist = transpose(zeros(N+1,1));

ylist(1) = yzero; 

for i=1:N
    term = f(tlist(i),ylist(i))*h;
    ylist(i+1) = ylist(i) + term;
end

yrange = Y(tlist);

% modified to generate a new figure window each time.
figure;

plot(tlist,yrange,'red','LineWidth', 2);
hold;
plot(tlist,ylist,'blue','LineWidth', 2);
plot(tlist, abs(yrange - ylist),'magenta','LineWidth', 2)

% modified to wrap the title.
title({'Graphs of the True Solution, Euler Solution,', 'and the Absolute Value of the Global Error (GE)'})
xlabel('t')
ylabel('Y(t)')

legend({'True Solution','Euler Solution', 'Absolute Value of the GE'},'Location','southwest')

end
```

I now try and call this function in another script. The variables `f` and `Y` in the function are symbolic functions; so, in the other file, I first declare these functions before calling this function. Here's the code:

```
clc

syms f(t,y)
syms Y(t)

f(t,y) = -y + 2.0*cos(t); %This the derivative of the function whose solution we're trying to computed
Y(t) = sin(t) + cos(t); %This is the true solution;

% Calling function

EulerMethod(0.0, 6.0, 0.2, f, Y, 1.0);
```

I, however, get errors when I run the second script. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong? I suspect this may be because of the way I have both input and used the symbolic functions `f` and `Y` but I am not sure.

Comment: To declare an anonymous function, use the @ operator: `f = @(t,y) -y + 2.0*cos(t)` and `Y = @(t) sin(t) + cos(t)`. Then you can pass `f` and `Y` to another function and use it like a symbolic function there. You don't need the `syms` at all, in my opinion.

Comment: Symbolic functions will likely slow this code down, and are totally overkill here. As Florian suggests, use [anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) instead.

Comment: Please include the actual errors you get? I copy-pasted your script and it works just fine for me.